# Richfaces 4 select only gets rendered correctly after a site refresh

Tags: ajax, jsf, select, richfaces, page-refresh

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it might be a bug or something.

My setup contains IntelliJ IDEA 12, JBoss AS 7.2.0.Final, Richfaces 4.3.4 within a war-File within an ear-Project (no Maven).

I have this index-page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <rich:notifyMessage stayTime="3500" showShadow="true" showCloseButton="true" />
    <f:view>
        <h:head>    <title>     title   </title>    </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <!-- some more divs for page-design, but commented out at the moment -->
            <div id="page">
                <div id="index_workspace" style="width:1000px;margin:auto;">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="index_workspace_table">
                        <rich:panel id="index_workspace_navi_left" style="width:180px;min-height:600px;max-height:600px;">
                            <ui:include src="general/navi_left.xhtml"/>
                        </rich:panel>
                        <rich:panel id="index_workspace_content" style="width:550px; min-height:600px; max-height:600px;" rendered="#{not empty naviBean.content}">
                            <a4j:outputPanel id="index_workspace_content_ajax" ajaxRendered="true">
                                    <ui:include src="#{naviBean.content}" id="current_site" />
                            </a4j:outputPanel>
                        </rich:panel>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </div>
            <!-- some more divs for page-design, but commented out at the moment -->
            </div>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

Within the  section I load the pages with forms and all the other cool stuff RF brings. But I have a rendering problem with this part of a loaded page:

```
<rich:select id="someID_1" rendered="true" immediate="true" required="true" enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="someLabel">
    <a4j:ajax render="true">
        <f:selectItems id="selectlist" value="#{BackingBean.SelectableItem-ListGetter}"/>
    </a4j:ajax>
</rich:select>
```

**And here my problem is located:**

This drop-down list only gets rendered on a page reload, e.g. F5 or CTRL-R action.
Also I could observe that if I set this element on some Kind of a "start page" (initially loaded on the index.xhtml) it gets rendered very well. In this case every other page containing this kind of element renders it correctly also.

I tried

- updating JSF from 2.1 to 2.2.1 - that only brought up more problems - so I rolled it back.
- The "standard" h:selectOneMenu behaves the same.
- additional options within rich:select (e.g.: rendered, immediate, required, ...)
- different ajax commands within the navigation (server, client, ajax, on different levels)
- googling around since days - found no useable hint

I would appreciate every hint that guides me into the right direction as I feel confident, that I make some mistake I can't figure out...

Additionally my navigation looks like this (in another div on the index.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <h:form id="navi_left">
        <rich:panel>
            <rich:panelMenu itemMode="ajax" groupMode="ajax" itemChangeListener="#{naviBean.updateContent}" >
            <rich:panelMenuGroup itemLeftIcon="disc" label="Erfassung" name="#{naviBean.content}">
                <rich:panelMenuItem label="someLabel_navi" name="path/to/page-not-getting-rendered-well.xhtml"/>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
         </rich:panel>
    </h:form>
</ui:component>
```

Hope this helps helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. As my navigation and my desired site with the not correctly rendered component lie nested in <div>s on the third participating site - my index.xhtml - it seems to be impossible to let a jsf-component be rendered without having all (i.e. the navigation and the desired) sites processed on the server. So the following code-snippets work for my situation:

index.xhtml snippet:

```
<rich:panel id="index_workspace_content" style="width:550px; min-height:600px; max-height:600px;" rendered="#{not empty naviBean.content}">
    <ui:include src="#{naviBean.content}" id="current_site" />
</rich:panel>
```

navi_left.xhtml snippet:

```
<h:form id="navi_left">
    <rich:panel>
        <rich:panelMenu itemMode="server" groupMode="client" itemChangeListener="#{naviBean.updateContent}">
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="someLabel" name="#{naviBean.content}">
                <rich:panelMenuItem label="anotherLabel" name="path/to/page-being-rendered-correctly.xhtml"/>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
...
</h:form>
```

component snippet in the desired.xhtml:

```
<rich:select id="someId" rendered="true" immediate="true" required="true" enableManualInput="true">
    <f:selectItems var="#{backingBean.selectableItemList}" id="selectlist" value="#{backingBean.predefinedItem}"/>
</rich:select>
```

So what I have changed is the **itemMode** to "server", both of the others (ajax and client) will not work!
Setting the groupMode to "client" does not affect the renderprocess of desired.xhtml as it only describes the way the rich:panelMenu behaves.

What makes me feel a bit confused is, that the URL now gets extended with a "/index.xhtml". Before the change it was always just the url:port/context (e.g. localhost:8080/app ).

So it works now, but maybe it's not really what I wanted. I'll observe and report future facts concerning this **itemMode**-option here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a4j:ajax render="true">
    <f:selectItems id="selectlist" value="#{BackingBean.SelectableItem-ListGetter}"/>
</a4j:ajax>
```

The above construct is not legal(as you've already seen yourself). The `render` attribute in there is not used for what you'd expect: to conditionally render the component; Rather, it's supposed to contain a list of on-page components to update via ajax.

To achieve the output I presume you're trying to get, you should use the following instead:

```
    <a4j:region>
       <rich:select id="someID_1" rendered="true" immediate="true" required="true" enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="someLabel">
          <f:selectItems id="selectlist" value="#{BackingBean.SelectableItem-ListGetter}"/>
       </rich:select>
    <a4j:region>
```

Comment: Thanks kolossus for these hints.I'll use that to dive deeper into that ajax behaviour. Sadly only using the region doesn't solve my problem with the not rendered richfaces components.

Comment: @phradr - you mean the `<rich:select/>` is not rendered still?

Comment: -Yes. I need a manual site refresh to have that component rendered correctly.